# JPA detached entity as part of a managed entity during merge

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.1

I have an in-application cache of some plain simple Entity beans (EJB 3.1, Glassfish,  EclipseLink), so that I don't have to look them up in database with findById each time since application needs to be fast. These entity beans are read-only.

So for example entity bean Country or Currency is in the local cache.

Some process in the Java EE application occurs that wishes to update a complex entity bean (i.e. Customer), which uses the simple beans above (Country, Currency...).

What happens then is that, because the connection of simple entity beans to the JPA context is lost, when .merge() is attempted on the Customer bean, JPA wishes to save the simple entity beans as new records in the database, although these exist 100% in the database already, so I guess this is a "detached entity" problem.

Example.

```
Country country = getFromCacheByName("GB"); // detached entity, but exists in database
Customer customer = getCustomerFromJPA(); // existing JPA attached entity
customer.setCountry(country);
EntityManager.merge(customer); // pseudo code
```

How to fix the last line, or the bean (Customer) itself, so that it does not try to save the dependant object (Country) on .merge()  ?

Thank you.

Comment: Just as a comment, I have attempted to .merge(country) after retrieving it from cache, and it didn't work really, JPA still tries to persist the simple bean as part of a transaction (last line of code above). Anyhow I don't need these simple beans merged, I just want them not to be persisted as new records in database since they already exist.

Comment: Not related to original problem, have you considered using foreign-key to `Country` instead of setting it in `Customer` & then merging. I presume you will have country object prior creating customer.

Comment: Hi Nayan, I don't really understand your proposal. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Something like `customer.setCountryId(country.getId())`, not to include the whole country object, but its primary key for referential integrity.

Comment: Hi there, yes this would work. But what's the point of all of this JPA complexity if simple things cannot be done (I am asking myself)? :)

Comment: I thought about your idea a bit, and it is not an option for me, because I cannot do later customer.getCountry().getCountryName() in UI... and it is a major pain if I cannot do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do a find() or merge() on the country before setting it in the Customer.  Also, ensure it has the correct Id.

Merge on Customer should also work though, it is odd that it would attempt to insert the country if its Id was existing, but this could depend on how you have configured things.  Are you cascading the merge on the country relationship?

Note that EclipseLink has its own cache.  So your application cache is probably not needed.

Comment: I tried doing EntityManager.merge(country) - it didn't help. Regarding EclipseLink cache and JPA cache in general. I have in code at many places something like daoSomething.findByName("a") which returns simple entity (i.e. Currency). And each time it goes to database and does SELECT ... FROM currency WHERE ID = ... As if no caching exists at all. Any idea how to activate cache in EclipseLink? I am talking about totally trivial things like getting simple entity by ID or one column.

Comment: "Are you cascading the merge on the country relationship" - regarding this, I have no CascadeType set on any relationship, so it should be default. So Customer just has a simple property @ManyToOne Country country; and there are no more annotations.

Comment: This was my bad. Actually merge() on parent object does work, the code I was using is a bit more complex and the .merge() was simply not invoked. Thanks for your kind answers.